# Flutter get file name

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
String fileName = _profPic.path.split('/').last;
print(fileName);
```

Output is `Screenshot_2020-05-12-17-14-07-564_com.miui.home.png`
but I require only `home.png`

Comment: The output you are getting is the file name, and the output you want is part of the file name. You have to manipulate the string to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible `path` or `dart` can decide which parts of the name you need.

You must manipulate the string. In your case, this method will do what you need:

```
String getName(String fullName){
  final parts = fullName.split('.');
  return parts.skip(parts.length - 2).take(2).join('.');
}
```

example:

```
final name = 'Screenshot_2020-05-12-17-14-07-564_com.miui.home.png';
print(getName(name)); // home.png
```

Or, you can convert this method into an `extension`.